# How to let string coming with HTML tags to be rendered in React js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on my website with Reactjs and Django. I have WISYWIG eidtor in Django admin, so when I publish posts with text decorations, it's stored with HTML tags.

In React, I fetch the API from Django REST framework to get the post. When I render the string data in React, it just shows up with HTML tags.

For example,

Django Admin
I store **Hello, world!** and it's stored as `<b>Hello, world!</b>`. Then, I make API with it.

In React,

I fetch the API and render it in React component, but it just shows up like `<b>Hello, world!</b>`, insteand of **Hello, world!**.

Should I use any module to render it like that?

**UPDATE**

Here are the codes where I have the problem.

```
{storeList.map(store => {
  return (
    <Card className={classes.card} key={store.id}>
      <CardBody>
        <div className={classes.cardBody}>
          <h6 className={classes.cardSubtitle}>
            {store.shortDesc} <-- This part has the problem
          </h6>
        </div>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Updated it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might need to provide a bit more context around your actual issue but I'll venture trying to help.  If you have a string that includes HTML tags, then when rendering, use the **dangerouslySetInnerHtml** property

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: yourStringWithHtmlInIt }} />;
```

this will then property render the HTML.  For more info see https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

**EDIT:**

```
{storeList.map(store => {   return (
    <Card className={classes.card} key={store.id}>
      <CardBody>
        <div className={classes.cardBody}>
          <h6 className={classes.cardSubtitle}>
             <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: store.shortDesc }} />;
          </h6>
        </div>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>   ); })}
```

Comment: Sorry for making broad question. I'm kind of lost to properly use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in my codes. Should I use it right away before passing through props? Also, updated the post with my codes

Comment: @Jay does the edit help?  I think I'm understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: It helped a lot! It says it needs `__html` thing so edited your post to make sure. Thank you for the help @JoeCo!