# Cannot break the line in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have to break the text in my react application. I have this situation:

```js
export default function App() {
  let multilineString = `My
text
is
here`;

  let htmlText = multilineString.replace(/(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "<br>");
  console.log(htmlText);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{htmlText}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I expect to break the text like:

> My
> text
> is
> here

But I get this: `My<br>text<br>is<br>here`.

Why do I get this result and how to get the expected one?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-nova-bf27h?file=/src/App.js:24-333

Comment: In React, dangerouslySetInnerHTML is replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM.  So Try <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlText}}></h1>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to let string coming with HTML tags to be rendered in React js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766630/how-to-let-string-coming-with-html-tags-to-be-rendered-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

The string variables inside JSX are always rendered as plain text, not as HTML, so you can not display any HTML elements (like `<br>`).

The best solution is to use CSS to display new lines (without having to do any replacements):

```
.App h1 {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```
export default function App() {
  let multilineString = `My
text
is
here`;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{multilineString}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-cookies-fi4y8?file=/src/App.js**

**DOCS: [CSS white-space MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)**

Answer (score 0):

In React, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. Replace `<h1>{htmlText}</h1>` with `<h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlText}}></h1>` and it will work.

```
import "./styles.css";
export default function App() {
      let multilineString = `My
    text
    is
    here`;
    
      let htmlText = multilineString.replace(/(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, "<br>");
      console.log(htmlText);
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: htmlText}}></h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have `multilineString` is a string. You can't add `<br/>` between words and expect them to act like the would in html elements. Here is how you can achieve what you are looking for:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let multilineString = `My
text
is
here`;
  let splitted = multilineString.split(/(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g);
  const joined = splitted.map((word) => (
    <h1>
      {word}
      <br />
    </h1>
  ));
  console.log(multilineString);

  console.log(joined);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {joined}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing difficulties in line breaking in **dangerouslySetInnerHTML**. Previously it was a long single line goes out of the box.

In **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** used **overFlowWrap** and **wordWrap** and it works perfectly. **[This blog is a gem for react line breaking related issues.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)**

```
<span style={{
  overflowWrap: "break-word",
  wordWrap: "break-word"
  }} 
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: preview_lines.join("\n")}} />
```